# Get angular Observable stream as array

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have list, that should simulate the stream :

```ts
list = [
  {name : 'Str1', age: 10},
  {name : 'Str2', age: 10},
  {name : 'Str3', age: 10}
];
```

and I've created an `Observable` from this list:

```ts
Observable.from(this.list).skip(this.currentPage * this.pageSize).take(this.pageSize).subscribe(data => this.pagerList = data, console.error);
```

And in the subscribe method I get the values one by one. How I'm supposed to wait for the whole data to be returned and then to get the whole list. There is take() operator, and after it the Observable have to stop.

I don't want to put every value one by one in the array.

I'm new here, not only for angular, but for javascript as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried to use `toArray` operator?.

```js
let list = [
  { name: 'Str1', age: 10 },
  { name: 'Str2', age: 10 },
  { name: 'Str3', age: 10 },
  { name: 'Str4', age: 10 },
  { name: 'Str5', age: 10 },
  { name: 'Str6', age: 10 }
];

let currentPage = 2;
let pageSize = 2;

Rx.Observable.from(list)
  .skip(currentPage * pageSize)
  .take(pageSize)
  .toArray()
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data), console.error);
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The `scan` operator should do what you want

```ts
Observable.from(this.list)
.skip(this.currentPage * this.pageSize)
.take(this.pageSize)
.scan([], acc, curr) => {acc.push(curr); return acc;});
.subscribe(data => this.pagerList = data, console.error);
```

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-scan

Comment: http://rxmarbles.com/#scan this is like reduce but after the result is received. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: With `scan`you get an updated array after each event and with `toArray` you only get one array at the end when the observable completes.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more appropriate solution:

```
Observable.of(this.list).map(x => x.slice(this.currentPage * this.pageSize)).map(x => x.slice(0, this.pageSize)).subscribe(data => this.pagerList = data, console.error);
```

Comment: I don't understand this one. In the first map function you get object. How can you slice object?

Comment: `Observable.of(this.list)` creates sequence of one element which type is array, `map` is applied to observable value, in this case it is array.