# Using async instead of .subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've an `Observable` on `errors$` field in my `LoginComponent`:

```
private alerts: Array<Object>;
private errors$: Observable<IError>;
constructor()
{
    this.alerts = [];
    this.errors$ = //initialization...
}
```

where `IError` is:

```
export interface IError {
    code: string;
    timestamp: string;
    msg: string;
    type: string;
}
```

Currently, I'm creating a subscription to this `Observable` by hand:

```
this.errorsSub = this.errors$.subscribe(
    (error: IError) => {
        if (error.code != null)
            this.addAlert(error.msg);
        else
            this.clearAlerts();
    }
);
```

where

```
private addAlert(message: string): void {
    this.alerts.push({type: 'danger', msg: message});
}

private clearAlerts(): void {
    this.alerts.splice(0, this.alerts.length);
}
```

I'm binding `alerts` array in my html using an `ngFor`:

```
<div
    <alert *ngFor="let alert of alerts; let i = index" [type]="alert.type + ' alert-sm'" (close)="closeAlert(i)" dismissible="true">
        <div [innerHTML]="alert.msg"></div>
    </alert>
</div>
```

So, I'd like to use `async` pipe in order to do that. I know that's possible but I don't quite figure out how to do it... I only want to show the last notification error has been notified.

So the goal is remove `alerts` array.

I don't know if I've explained so well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `async` pipe just subscribes to the Observable and prints the latest item emitted. So in your situations you want make another Observable that will filter all items with `error.code != null` and use `async` on it.

```
this.errorsFiltered$ = this.errors$
    .filter(error => error.code != null)
    .share();
```

Then subscribe to this Observable:

```
<alert *ngIf="errorsFiltered$ | async" [type]="(errorsFiltered$ | async).type + ' alert-sm'"  ....>
    ...
</alert>
```

I'm using `share()` to always create only one subscription to the source Observable. However it might not be necessary depending on where the `this.errors$` is coming from. If it's an HTTP request it would make multiple subscriptions without `share()`.

Comment: Probably, it's not related with this question. Nevertheless, I'm getting this message: `TypeError: this.store$.select(...).filter is not a function`. Could you help me?

Comment: @Jordi See this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#rxjs-library

Comment: Let me ask you again for another issue I don't quite figure out on yout approach. What's exactly `*ngIf` for? I'm guessing it's only be valid up to a first value is reached, isn't it? From a first "value" on the subscription is reached then it's going to be true, isn't it? I don't know if Ive explained so well.

Comment: The `*ngIf` is to make sure you're not displaying the `<alert>` element when there's no `error`. However it's true that in this you probably don't want to use the `filter()` operator.

Comment: When you say `there's no error`, what exactly do you mean? the stream is empty? when error.code == null`?

Comment: When there's no error probably means in you example that `error.code === null`. In other words `this.errors$` emits something that doesn't have any `code` property (or `code === null`)

Answer (score 1):

The `|async` pipe is use to subscribe to observables. If you push the data into an array, it's not an observable anymore:

```
<alert *ngFor="let alert of errors$; let i = index"
```

**update**

```
<alert [type]="(errors$ | async).type + ' alert-sm'" (close)="closeAlert()" dismissible="true">
    <div [innerHTML]="(errors$ | async).msg"></div>
</alert>
```

Comment: The goal i replace pushing data into an array instead of using `async` instead. So, the goal is remove `alerts` array.

Comment: You might need to use the `scan()` operator to collect the distinct events into an array. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330211/get-angular-observable-stream-as-array/42330259#42330259

Comment: Why do you put them in an array, and why are you using `*ngFor` if you only want the last one?

Comment: I want to change it. I only want to show the last alert from now on.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer. The next question is what about if you are using two `async` pipe to the same one `Observable`? Is it going to create two subscriptions or only one?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I think the last comment I saw was that it subscribes twice.